# Application error on deployed django rest framework app on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my django rest framework app on Heroku. I read many other similar questions  but I'm confused. My app structure is not right or I'm missing something.

This is my structure on git:

```
 .gitignore  
 requirements.txt 
 src
    |
    --authorization
    --core
    --static
    --staticfiles
    --Procfile
    --manage.py
    --suacm
        |
        ---asgi.py
        ---settings.py
        ---urls.py
        ---wsgi.py
```

authorization and core are apps under my django project. there wasn't static or staticfiles before heroku deploy. But it automatically created staticfiles. Then I also created static and followed instructions to make it work via changes in settings.py. It'd be awesome if someone help me figure out my problem on heroku and why it doesn't work.

This is Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn suacm.wsgi
web: gunicorn suacm:app
```

When I run app with this command my app works fine and run locally:

```
gunicorn suacm.wsgi:application
```

But I couldn't solve the error in deployed app.

With

```
heroku logs --tail
```

I receive errors starts like below:

```
2021-05-21T14:32:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-21T14:32:26.505788+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=suacm.herokuapp.com request_id=dfeba2ff-fa7d-4dfb-9337-706f50d286dc fwd="82.222.237.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-21T14:32:26.882608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=suacm.herokuapp.com request_id=292525ae-bc4e-49c7-b979-e455bbfd6b95 fwd="82.222.237.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

When I run this

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 --app suacm
```

I get this:

```
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

And finally when I try to run heroku locally under src folder with this command

```
src % heroku local web
```

I get this response:

```
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (35246)
[INFO] Using worker: sync
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 35247
Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'suacm'.
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 35247)
.
.
```

If needed, this is my requirements.txt file:

```
django_environ==0.4.5
djangorestframework_simplejwt==4.6.0
django_filter==2.4.0
Django==3.1.3
djangorestframework==3.12.4
environ==1.0
PyJWT==2.1.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
django-on-heroku==1.1.2
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

This is my first time deploying a django app. I hope I gave enough information. Just ask if there is more information needed.

Comment: Your Procfile seems wrong to me. Try this in procfile ```web: gunicorn src.mainfolder.wsgi --log-file -``` remove the other web declaration

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately it didn't work. I'm having same errors. @Sumithran

Comment: can you share the full error log.

Comment: I edited my question. After build succeed I got those. Also i changed folder name 'mainfolder' to the original which is 'suacm'. @Sumithran

Comment: did you check the below given answer?

Comment: While I was waiting for an answer I changed the structure of the app and made procfile. So web: gunicorn suacm.wsgi worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Procfile in the root directory, not in the src and

change this

```
web: gunicorn suacm.wsgi
```

to

```
web: gunicorn src.suacm.wsgi
```

#### Then why it work on a local server?

In your local setup, you are launching the server from the `src` directory which is not the root directory!
But the in the production Heroku launches the application from the root directory, since there is no Procfile in the root directory you are getting these errors.